# Youtube Api - "Authorization Required You need to authorize access before proceeding" Error

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want video upload to Youtube with php. First, i enabled YouTube Data API v3 on Google Developer Page and i receive client id, client secret. And set my ip adress (Public API access)

I use this library https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client. And i tried this code

```
<?php


// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once 'src/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'src/Google/Service/YouTube.php';
session_start();

/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * Google Developers Console <https://console.developers.google.com/>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'xxx';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxx';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    echo "asd";
  try{
    // REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
    $videoPath = "file.mp4";

    // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
    // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
    // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
    // video category.
    $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle("Test title");
    $snippet->setDescription("Test description");
    $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));

    // Numeric video category. See
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list 
    $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

    // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
    // "private" and "unlisted".
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
    $status->privacyStatus = "public";

    // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
    $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
    // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
    // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
    $client->setDefer(true);

    // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
    $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

    // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $insertRequest,
        'video/*',
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


    // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
      $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }

    fclose($handle);

    // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
    $client->setDefer(false);


    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Video Uploaded</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
        $status['snippet']['title'],
        $status['id']);

    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

  } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Uploaded</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?=$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```

I get error 
"Authorization Required. You need to authorize access before proceeding."
message 
What should i do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need public API access for this.
If you create an OAuth2 access as an "installed application" and put clientid and secret back to this code in their places, that will work.

Comment: Hi. I create "installed application" ,i refresh my cliendid and secretid.but problem continue still.

Comment: that should open up your browser when you first run it, and you'll sign on.