# Getting Authorization Required Error with youtube API call in CodeIgniter

Tags: php

I am new to youtube data API, I want to let users from my website to upload directly to my youtube channel but I am a beginner in this aspect and this is what my client ask me to do.

I tried to use the example on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php but all that I get is:

> Authorization Required You need to authorize access before proceeding.

I don't know anything concerning this topic. I am using the CodeIgniter PHP framework. This is the sample code I copied from Google Developer:

```html
<?php
 public function youtube(){
        if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../party/to/google/vendor/autoload.php')) {
            throw new \Exception('please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "' . __DIR__ .'"');
        }
        require_once __DIR__ . '/../party/to/google/vendor/autoload.php';
        //session_start();
/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * {{ Google Cloud Console }} <{{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'My Cleint Id';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'My Client Secret';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('https:' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
// Check if an auth token exists for the required scopes
$tokenSessionKey = 'token-' . $client->prepareScopes();
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    $data['messages'] = 'The session state did not match.';
  }
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
  redirect($redirect,'refresh');
}
if (isset($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey]);
}
// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $data['messages'] = '';
  try{
    // REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
    $videoPath = base_url('path/to/thevideo/video.mp4');
    // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
    // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
    // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
    // video category.
    $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle("Test title");
    $snippet->setDescription("Test description");
    $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));
    // Numeric video category. See
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
    $snippet->setCategoryId("22");
    // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
    // "private" and "unlisted".
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
    $status->privacyStatus = "public";
    // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
    $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);
    // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
    // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
    // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
    $client->setDefer(true);
    // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
    $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);
    // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $insertRequest,
        'video/*',
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));
    // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
      $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
    $client->setDefer(false);
    $data['messages'] .= "<h3>Video Uploaded</h3><ul>";
    $data['messages'] .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
        $status['snippet']['title'],
        $status['id']);
    $data['messages'] .= '</ul>';
  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $data['messages'] .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $data['messages'] .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }
  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
} elseif ($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID == 'REPLACE_ME') {
  $data['messages'] = <<<END
  <h3>Client Credentials Required</h3>
  <p>
    You need to set <code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> and
    <code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> before proceeding.
  <p>
END;
} else {
  // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $data['messages'] = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
$this->template->load('public_layout','contents','youtube_testing_view',$data);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is it wise to take on client work that you're unable to do? That might get you into a bit of a pickle, surely?

Comment: No. That was not the agreement from start  we just have to consider it in order to have more space on the server. I have completed the work already . but we just have to consider using youtube to host all the video that user uploaded in other to save the disc space. Please help me out. I just need some idea. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679550/youtube-api-authorization-required-you-need-to-authorize-access-before-procee) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33430549/you-need-to-authorize-access-before-proceeding), and [several more in this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=youtube+api+You+need+to+authorize+access+before+proceeding).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You need to authorize access before proceeding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33430549/you-need-to-authorize-access-before-proceeding)

Comment: [This link](https://www.domsammut.com/code/php-server-side-youtube-v3-oauth-api-video-upload-guide) comes up in a search also.

Comment: Thank you, i got to solve that problem. now i need to get the Access token from the call back page but with all i have done what i get is "array" string is there any insight on this please

Comment: Great, would you ask a fresh question about that? It sounds like a different problem, for which you will need to show new information.